# Locking postgresql table

Tags: database, postgresql, locking, psql, table-lock

Is it possible to lock a table for a specified time in PostgreSQL database by running psql commands via shell script or sql file?

If we run the LOCK TABLE command, when the script exits the lock will also be gone, so that is not sufficient.

Comment: Why do you want to lock a table for a longer time than the script? You are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `pg_sleep` for your specified time in conjunction with `LOCK TABLE`? Something like the script below should lock a table for 60 seconds (note this is untested):

```
BEGIN WORK;
LOCK TABLE MyTable IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
SELECT pg_sleep(60);
COMMIT WORK;
```

- [LOCK documentation page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-lock.html)
- [Delaying Execution section at the bottom of the date/time functions doc page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: If the suggested script works, then please mark this as the accepted answer and upvote when possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pg_sleep()`, `pg_sleep_for()` and `pg_sleep_until()` to lock a table for a specified time as shown below according to [Delaying Execution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-DELAY):

```sql
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE person;
SELECT pg_sleep(10);
COMMIT;
```

```sql
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE person;
SELECT pg_sleep_for('20 seconds');
COMMIT;
```

```sql
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE person;
SELECT pg_sleep_for('3 minutes');
COMMIT;
```

```sql
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE person;
SELECT pg_sleep_until('today 21:45');
COMMIT;
```

```sql
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE person;
SELECT pg_sleep_until('tomorrow 03:00');
COMMIT;
```